# 2006 Dodge Grand Caravan - Rear blower won't blow hot air, only cold

Tags: dodge, heater, grand-caravan

My 2006 Dodge Grand Caravan rear blower won't blow air through the vents when the setting is set to "HOT". If you move the setting to "COLD", air will flow through the vents.  This is the case for both the control up front and the rear control.

What could be causing this?  How do I diagnose this?

Comment: Could be a blockage to, or in, the rear heater core. Has the cooling system been flushed? You may want to take a look at [this post](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/94848/fan+works+but+no+heat+comes+into+cabin.+Troubleshooting+ideas). It may prove helpful to you. Since I don't know what exactly is wrong with your van, I am only posting as a comment.

Comment: The amount of air coming out of the vents is the issue - when the air setting is on the highest of heat, the air flow in the vents is nothing, yet flipping to the coldest results in air flow in the vents to normal.

I guess i don't see how a blockage in the heater core can affect the air flow in the vents.

Comment: You said "*won't blow hot air through the vents*". I took that as the air was coming out, it just wasn't hot. So you mean it "won't blow air thru the vents when it is set to heat"? Did you check out the link in my comment? There is some good info in the answer about checking/resetting the system.

Comment: Ugh - yeah, I'm tired today - wrote the original incorrect - will correct it.  Anyway, yes, I've looked at the link.  I'll see if I can get it working with those tips.  Thanks.

Comment: Followed that post - no luck with it doing the "A/C Heater Control Calibration" - it did the blinking of the lights and under 2 minutes they stopped blinking and turned off.  Still same result, when the setting is set to heat, no air flow through the vents (which are located above the head).